# CORS error caused due to a web API(access-control-allow-origin)

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to use a web API in javascript but I repeatedly keep getting this error:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token={token}'
>   from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/*' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an
>   opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
>   to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How should I resolve this? I installed a plugin to set the desirable header but others can't install the plugin to view data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you meant, but it's the HTTP response from your API at 'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/' that must include the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header in its HTTP responses.

If the value of that header is 'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/*', your web browser will trigger a CORS error if you call that API from code hosted in any domain other than 'https://eodhistoricaldata.com'. To fix this, you need to change the value your API returns for this header to the domain you want to allow to call your API.

Returning the value * for the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header will allow applications from any domain to call your API without a CORS error.